# Show an altitude of triangle is angle bisector

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Points $M$ and $N$ are on sides $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{AB}$ of $\triangle ABC$. Lines $\overline{BM}$ and $\overline{CN}$ intersect each other on altitude of $\overline{AD}$ of $\triangle ABC$.

> Show that $\overline{AD}$ bisects $\angle MDN$.

[image]

Comment: What did you do already?

Comment: I found your post in the long unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

Let the mentioned intersection point be H. Locate Q on BC such that AQ cut CN at C’ with $\angle CC’A = 90^0$.

[image]

After the above construction, H is the orthocenter of $\triangle ACQ$; and therefore Q(H)Q’ is the third altitude. Then, $\triangle DQ’C’$ is orthic with $$\lambda = \lambda’ …. (1)$$.

Also, CDC’A is cyclic (in red). Let DQ’ produced and DM produced cut the red circle at I and J respectively. AJ will cut DI at K. Then, $$\gamma = \gamma_1 =\gamma_2$$.

Construct the green circle passing through A, K, and D. It will cut AQ at R and DC’ produced at S. Then, $\theta = \theta’$ and AK = AS (because of (1)).

By AAS, $\triangle KIA \cong \triangle SC’A$. Therefore, m = n.

Finally, $m’ + \lambda = m + \lambda = n + \lambda’ = n’ + \lambda’$.